# Wordpress- counting posts of all users

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, plugins

I working on my simple plugin for WordPress. This plugin should count all users posts and print them in the table. But I have a problem. I use for loop to get data from MySQL and then put it to $result array. Then I use foreach loop to print them in HTML table. It doesn't work properly because `only 1 (last) record` is printed in the table (should be 6 records). Do you have any ideas? Thanks in advance.

```
 global $wpdb; 
    $result = count_users();
    $total_users = $result['total_users'];

    for($id = 1;$id<=$total_users;$id++){ //there is 6 users i database


     $result = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT wp_users.ID, wp_users.display_name, COUNT(wp_posts.post_author) AS 'Number_of_posts' FROM wp_users INNER JOIN wp_posts ON wp_users.ID = wp_posts.post_author WHERE  wp_posts.post_type = 'post'  AND wp_users.ID = $id AND wp_posts.post_status = 'publish'" , ARRAY_A);
};

 echo '<table>';
foreach ($result as $x){
    echo'<tr>'; 
                                       // only one is printed
    echo'<td>'.'ID: '. $x['ID']."</td>"; 
    echo'<td>'.'User : '. $x['display_name'].'</td>';
    echo'<td>'.'Number of posts :'. $x['Number_of_posts'].'</td>';
    echo'</tr>';



}

echo '</table>';
echo '<br>';
```

Comment: $result should array and use it as $result[] while assigning values

Comment: I would just use `get_users()` together with `query_posts( 'author=' . $theauthorid );`

Comment: also, your id's only goes from the (int)1 to the total of (int)6 - if users have been deleted etc - it will skew your MySQL

Answer (score 0):

Here `$result` is an array. When assigning some values should be used as `$result[]=$somevalue;`. Also, remove ";" from the closing brace of for loop.

```
global $wpdb; 
    $result = count_users();
    $total_users = $result['total_users'];

    for($id = 1;$id<=$total_users;$id++){ //there is 6 users i database


     $result[$id] = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT wp_users.ID, wp_users.display_name, COUNT(wp_posts.post_author) AS 'Number_of_posts' FROM wp_users INNER JOIN wp_posts ON wp_users.ID = wp_posts.post_author WHERE  wp_posts.post_type = 'post'  AND wp_users.ID = $id AND wp_posts.post_status = 'publish'" , ARRAY_A);
}
```

Or you can use this solution. Hope this will be helpful for you. [Count user posts by user ID, Post type, and Post status](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/43549/count-user-posts-by-user-id-post-type-and-post-status)

Comment: $result[$id] = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT wp_users.ID, wp_users.display_name, COUNT(wp_posts.post_author) AS 'Number_of_posts' FROM wp_users INNER JOIN wp_posts ON wp_users.ID = wp_posts.post_author WHERE  wp_posts.post_type = 'post'  AND wp_users.ID = $id AND wp_posts.post_status = 'publish'" , ARRAY_A);
and now it print 8 rows in table without any data  from database ;/

Answer (score 0):

You can use `count_user_posts` to get any user post in wordpress. So you don't need to write any query for that. Please check below link
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/count_user_posts/

And to get user loop you can`get_users`.
https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_users

Answer (score 0):

The SQL string is modified to retrieve all needed records with just a single query.

**Use:**

```
SELECT wp_users.ID, wp_users.display_name, COUNT(wp_posts.post_author) AS 'Number_of_posts' FROM wp_users 
INNER JOIN wp_posts ON wp_users.ID = wp_posts.post_author 
WHERE wp_posts.post_type = 'post' AND wp_posts.post_status = 'publish'
GROUP BY wp_posts.post_author
```

`$wpdb->get_results()` has to be moved out of the first for loop. The first for loop is unnecessary, therefore removed.

**Updated Code:**

```
global $wpdb; 
$result = count_users();
$total_users = $result['total_users'];

$result = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT wp_users.ID, wp_users.display_name, COUNT(wp_posts.post_author) AS 'Number_of_posts' FROM wp_users 
INNER JOIN wp_posts ON wp_users.ID = wp_posts.post_author 
WHERE wp_posts.post_type = 'post' AND wp_posts.post_status = 'publish'
GROUP BY wp_posts.post_author" , ARRAY_A);

echo '<table border="1">';

foreach ($result as $x){
    echo'<tr>'; 
    echo'<td>'.'ID: '. $x['ID']."</td>"; 
    echo'<td>'.'User : '. $x['display_name'].'</td>';
    echo'<td>'.'Number of posts :'. $x['Number_of_posts'].'</td>';
    echo'</tr>';
}
echo '</table>';
echo '<br>';
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need get users with **post count** in custom query, you can try this:

```
global $wpdb;

$query = "SELECT users.*, posts.post_count FROM $wpdb->users users
        INNER JOIN (SELECT post_author, COUNT(*) as post_count FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_type = 'post' AND post_status = 'publish' GROUP BY post_author) posts ON (users.ID = posts.post_author)
        WHERE users.user_status = 1
        ORDER BY posts.post_count DESC            
        LIMIT 0, 10";

return $wpdb->get_results($query);
```